# Is base64_encode renaming my file before email send?

Tags: php

I'm using phpexcel to create a file.xls and then this small code i picked up to email me the xls as attachment. the problem is it sends the xls attachment as `filename = "._folder1_admin.xls"` instead of the actual filename `"admin.xls"`

It works fine if i define `$filename` without a sub-directory. but once i use the sub-dir like: `$filename = "./folder1/".$contextUser.".xls";` it screws up the filename in email.

i tried `html_entity_decode($filename)` but that didnt help..

this is the only code i can see it modifying filename before sending email

```
chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents("$filename")));
```

heres the whole code anyway:

```
$filename = "./folder1/".$contextUser.".xls";
$strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";
$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-874\n"; // or UTF-8 //
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";
$strContent1 = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents("$filename")));
$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\"\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strContent1."\n\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
$strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"\n\n";
```

You are setting the filename to the contents of `$filenme` and since `./folder1/admin.xls` is not valid filename, `/` are normalized to underscores. You may want to use `basename($filename)` in this place.